# Android data load is very slow even after pagination

Tags: android, kotlin

im loading data based on click of the button if user clicks on b1 button i load brand communities data and if b2 button i load all communinities the data from api is paginated and 10 communities per page but after loading 4 5 pages app starting to show app not responding and recyclerview is very slow what should i do now ??

```
package com.koraspond.petromin.communitySection

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.gzee.engage.utilities.UserInfoPreference
import com.gzee.engage.utilities.toast
import com.koraspond.petromin.R
import com.koraspond.petromin.communitySection.adaoters.CommunitiesAdapter
import com.koraspond.petromin.communitySection.models.AccountRequest.ChangeAccountRequest
import com.koraspond.petromin.communitySection.models.brandCommunityModel.BrandCommunityModel
import com.koraspond.petromin.communitySection.models.brandCommunityModel.Data
import com.koraspond.petromin.communitySection.models.petrominCommModel.PetCommModel
import com.koraspond.petromin.databinding.ActivityCommunityHomeScreenBinding
import com.koraspond.petromin.utils.Common
import com.koraspond.petromin.utils.JoinLeaveInterface
import com.koraspond.petromin.utils.LoadingDialog
import com.pegasus.pakbiz.network.Api
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext
import org.json.JSONException
import org.json.JSONObject
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Response
import kotlin.concurrent.thread


class CommunityHomeScreen : AppCompatActivity(),JoinLeaveInterface {
    lateinit var binding:ActivityCommunityHomeScreenBinding
    var petrominID:Int =0
    var isjoined=false
    var brandList:ArrayList<Data> = ArrayList()
    var selected:String = ""
    private var currentPage = 1
    private var totalPages = 0
    var isLoading = false
    lateinit var adapter: CommunitiesAdapter
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_community_home_screen)

        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this@CommunityHomeScreen,R.layout.activity_community_home_screen)

        binding.personLetterCv.setOnClickListener {
            finish()
        }

        binding.r2.setOnClickListener {
        if(isjoined) {
            val intent = Intent(this@CommunityHomeScreen,CommunityDetailScreen::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("id",petrominID)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
            else{
            val intent = Intent(this@CommunityHomeScreen,CommunitynotJoinedActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("id",petrominID)
            startActivity(intent)
            }
        }

        var loadingDialog = LoadingDialog(this@CommunityHomeScreen)
        binding.nscroll.setOnScrollChangeListener(NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener { v: NestedScrollView, scrollX: Int, scrollY: Int, oldScrollX: Int, oldScrollY: Int ->
            if (v.getChildAt(v.childCount - 1) != null) {
                if (scrollY >= v.getChildAt(v.childCount - 1)
                        .measuredHeight - v.measuredHeight &&
                    scrollY > oldScrollY
                ) {

                    if (currentPage <= totalPages) {

                        // Show the progress dialog

                        // Fetch the next page of home feed data
                        currentPage = currentPage + 1
                        if (!(currentPage > totalPages)) {
                            lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
                                if(selected.toString().equals("b1")){

                                    brandCommunities()

                                }
                                else{
                                    AllCommunities()
                                }
                            }
                        } else {

                        }

                        //  viewModel.getHomeFeed()

                    }
                    //code to fetch more data for endless scrolling
                }
            }
        } as NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener)

//        binding.commRcv.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
//            override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
//                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
//                val layoutManager = recyclerView.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager
//                Log.d("kjn", dy.toString())
//                //  Toast.makeText(requireActivity(),"yhn aya",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
//                // Check if the user has reached the end of the list
//                if ( layoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == brandList.size - 1) {
//
//                    // Load more data if there are more pages available
//                    if (currentPage <= totalPages) {
//
//                        // Show the progress dialog
//                        loadingDialog.start()
//                        // Fetch the next page of home feed data
//                        currentPage = currentPage + 1
//                        if (!(currentPage > totalPages)) {
//                           lifecycleScope.launchWhenResumed {
//                               if(selected.toString().equals("b1")){
//                                   brandCommunities()
//
//                               }
//                               else{
//                                   AllCommunities()
//                               }
//                           }
//                        } else {
//                            loadingDialog.stop()
//                        }
//
//                        //  viewModel.getHomeFeed()
//
//                    }
//                }
//            }
//        })
        val layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this@CommunityHomeScreen, 2)
        binding.commRcv.layoutManager = layoutManager
        adapter = CommunitiesAdapter(this@CommunityHomeScreen,brandList,this)

        binding.commRcv.adapter = adapter

        binding.b1.bringToFront()
        selected = "b1"
        binding.b1.setOnClickListener {
            binding.b1.bringToFront()
            currentPage = 1
            totalPages = 0
            selected = "b1"
            brandList.clear()
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            lifecycleScope.launchWhenResumed {
                brandCommunities()
            }
        }

        binding.b2.setOnClickListener {
            binding.b2.bringToFront()
            currentPage = 1
            totalPages = 0
            selected = "b2"
            brandList.clear()
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            lifecycleScope.launchWhenResumed {
                AllCommunities()
            }
        }
        binding.continueBtn.setOnClickListener {

            if (binding.continueBtn.text.toString()
                    .equals("Join")
            ) {
                var loadingDialog =
                    LoadingDialog(this@CommunityHomeScreen)
                var token =
                    "Bearer " + UserInfoPreference(this@CommunityHomeScreen).getStr(
                        Common.token
                    )

                loadingDialog.start()

                Api.client.joinComm(
                    Common.SecretKey,
                    token,
                   petrominID
                )
                    .enqueue(object :
                        retrofit2.Callback<ChangeAccountRequest> {
                        override fun onResponse(
                            call: Call<ChangeAccountRequest>,
                            response: Response<ChangeAccountRequest>
                        ) {
                            loadingDialog.stop()
                            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                                if (response.body()?.meta_data?.success == true && response.body()?.meta_data?.status_code == 201) {
                                    toast("Request Sent")
                                    binding.continueBtn.text =
                                        "Request Sent"

                                } else {

                                    if (response.body()?.meta_data?.message != null) {
                                        toast(response.body()?.meta_data?.message.toString())

                                    } else {


                                        // toast( "no Cars found")
                                    }
                                }
                            } else {

                                // nodata.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                                response?.errorBody()?.string()
                                    ?.let { responseBody ->
                                        println("Response Body: $responseBody")

                                        try {
                                            // Parse the JSON response to get the error message
                                            val errorJson =
                                                JSONObject(
                                                    responseBody
                                                )
                                            val errorMessage =
                                                errorJson.getJSONObject(
                                                    "meta_data"
                                                )
                                                    .getString("message")
                                            toast(errorMessage)
                                        } catch (e: JSONException) {
                                            e.printStackTrace()
                                            toast("Error parsing server response")
                                        }
                                    }
                            }
                        }

                        override fun onFailure(
                            call: Call<ChangeAccountRequest>,
                            t: Throwable
                        ) {
                            loadingDialog.stop()
                            toast(t.message.toString())

                        }

                    })
            }
        }





    }

    suspend fun brandCommunities()= withContext(Dispatchers.IO){



        val loadingDialog = withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            LoadingDialog(this@CommunityHomeScreen)
        }
        runOnUiThread {
            loadingDialog.start()
        }

        var userInfoPreference = UserInfoPreference(this@CommunityHomeScreen)
        var token = "Bearer "+ UserInfoPreference(this@CommunityHomeScreen).getStr("token")

        Api.client.getBrandComm(Common.SecretKey,token,UserInfoPreference(this@CommunityHomeScreen).getStr(Common.SelectedBrand),true,currentPage).enqueue(object :retrofit2.Callback<BrandCommunityModel>{
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<BrandCommunityModel>, response: Response<BrandCommunityModel>) {
                loadingDialog.stop()

                if (response.isSuccessful) {


                    if (response.body()?.meta_data?.success == true && response.body()?.meta_data?.status_code == 200 && response.body()?.payload != null) {
                        if(response.body()!=null && response.body()!!.payload!=null && response.body()!!.payload.data.size>0){
                            if (currentPage == 1) {
                                brandList.clear()
                            }
                            for(i in response.body()!!.payload.data){
                                brandList.add(i)
                            }
                            totalPages = response.body()!!.payload.meta.last_page
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                            binding.commRcv.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                            binding.noData.visibility = View.GONE

                        }
                        else{
                            binding.commRcv.visibility = View.GONE
                            binding.noData.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                            toast("no community found")
                        }
                    } else {
                        binding.commRcv.visibility = View.GONE
                        binding.noData.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                        toast(
                            (response.body()?.meta_data!!.message
                                ?: "unable to find cards").toString()
                        )
                    }
                } else {
                    binding.commRcv.visibility = View.GONE
                    binding.noData.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    response?.errorBody()?.string()?.let { responseBody ->
                        println("Response Body: $responseBody")

                        try {
                            // Parse the JSON response to get the error message
                            val errorJson = JSONObject(responseBody)
                            val errorMessage =
                                errorJson.getJSONObject("meta_data").getString("message")
                            toast(errorMessage)
                        } catch (e: JSONException) {
                            e.printStackTrace()
                            toast("Error parsing server response")
                        }
                    }
                    Log.d("djdj", response.errorBody().toString())
                }

            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<BrandCommunityModel>, t: Throwable) {
                loadingDialog.stop()
                isLoading = false
                binding.commRcv.visibility = View.GONE
                binding.noData.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                toast(t.message.toString())
            }


        })
    }
    suspend fun AllCommunities() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){

        val loadingDialog = withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            LoadingDialog(this@CommunityHomeScreen)
        }
        runOnUiThread {
            loadingDialog.start()
        }
        var userInfoPreference = UserInfoPreference(this@CommunityHomeScreen)
        var token = "Bearer "+ UserInfoPreference(this@CommunityHomeScreen).getStr("token")

        Api.client.getAllComm(Common.SecretKey,token,UserInfoPreference(this@CommunityHomeScreen).getStr(Common.SelectedBrand),true,currentPage).enqueue(object :retrofit2.Callback<BrandCommunityModel>{
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<BrandCommunityModel>, response: Response<BrandCommunityModel>) {
                loadingDialog.stop()

                if (response.isSuccessful) {

                    if (response.body()?.meta_data?.success == true && response.body()?.meta_data?.status_code == 200 && response.body()?.payload != null) {
                        if(response.body()!=null && response.body()!!.payload!=null && response.body()!!.payload.data.size>0){

                            loadingDialog.start()

                                if (currentPage == 1) {
                                    brandList.clear()
                                }
                                for (i in response.body()!!.payload.data) {
                                    brandList.add(i)
                                }
                                totalPages = response.body()!!.payload.meta.last_page
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                                loadingDialog.stop()
                                binding.commRcv.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                                binding.noData.visibility = View.GONE

                        }
                        else{
                            binding.commRcv.visibility = View.GONE
                            binding.noData.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                            toast("no community found")
                        }
                    } else {
                        binding.commRcv.visibility = View.GONE
                        binding.noData.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                        toast(
                            (response.body()?.meta_data!!.message
                                ?: "unable to find cards").toString()
                        )
                    }
                } else {
                    binding.commRcv.visibility = View.GONE
                    binding.noData.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    response?.errorBody()?.string()?.let { responseBody ->
                        println("Response Body: $responseBody")

                        try {
                            // Parse the JSON response to get the error message
                            val errorJson = JSONObject(responseBody)
                            val errorMessage =
                                errorJson.getJSONObject("meta_data").getString("message")
                            toast(errorMessage)
                        } catch (e: JSONException) {
                            e.printStackTrace()
                            toast("Error parsing server response")
                        }
                    }
                    Log.d("djdj", response.errorBody().toString())
                }

            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<BrandCommunityModel>, t: Throwable) {
                loadingDialog.stop()
                isLoading = false
                binding.commRcv.visibility = View.GONE
                binding.noData.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                toast(t.message.toString())
            }


        })


    }
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main){
            getPetrominCommunity()
            if (selected == "b1") {
                currentPage=1
                totalPages=0
                brandCommunities()
            } else {
                currentPage=1
                totalPages=0
                AllCommunities()
            }
        }
    }
    suspend fun getPetrominCommunity() {
        var loadingDialog = LoadingDialog(this@CommunityHomeScreen)
        var token = "Bearer " + UserInfoPreference(this@CommunityHomeScreen).getStr(Common.token)

        loadingDialog.start()

        Api.client.getPetrominComm(Common.SecretKey, token)
            .enqueue(object : retrofit2.Callback<PetCommModel> {
                override fun onResponse(call: Call<PetCommModel>, response: Response<PetCommModel>) {
                    loadingDialog.stop()
                    if (response.isSuccessful) {
                        runOnUiThread {
                            if (response.body()?.meta_data?.success == true && response.body()?.meta_data?.status_code == 200 && response.body()?.payload != null) {
                                binding.members.text =
                                    response.body()?.payload!!.members.toString() + " members"
                                petrominID = response.body()!!.payload.id

                                if (response.body()!!.payload!!.has_joined) {
                                    isjoined=true
                                    binding.continueBtn.text = "View Details"


                                } else {

                                    if(response.body()!!.payload.has_requested){
                                        binding.continueBtn.text = "Requested"

                                    }
                                    else {
                                        binding.continueBtn.text = "Join"

                                    }
                                }

                            } else {

                                if (response.body()?.meta_data?.message != null) {
                                    toast(response.body()?.meta_data?.message.toString())

                                } else {


                                    // toast( "no Cars found")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } else {

                        // nodata.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                        response?.errorBody()?.string()?.let { responseBody ->
                            println("Response Body: $responseBody")

                            try {
                                // Parse the JSON response to get the error message
                                val errorJson = JSONObject(responseBody)
                                val errorMessage =
                                    errorJson.getJSONObject("meta_data").getString("message")
                                toast(errorMessage)
                            } catch (e: JSONException) {
                                e.printStackTrace()
                                toast("Error parsing server response")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                override fun onFailure(call: Call<PetCommModel>, t: Throwable) {
                    loadingDialog.stop()
                    toast(t.message.toString())

                }

            })

    }

    override fun eventjoinLEave(pos: Int, type: Int) {
        //1 for join 2 for leave

        if(type==1){
            var loadingDialog =
                LoadingDialog(this@CommunityHomeScreen)
            var token =
                "Bearer " + UserInfoPreference(this@CommunityHomeScreen).getStr(
                    Common.token
                )

            loadingDialog.start()

            Api.client.joinComm(
                Common.SecretKey,
                token,
                brandList.get(pos).id
            )
                .enqueue(object :
                    retrofit2.Callback<ChangeAccountRequest> {
                    override fun onResponse(
                        call: Call<ChangeAccountRequest>,
                        response: Response<ChangeAccountRequest>
                    ) {
                        loadingDialog.stop()
                        if (response.isSuccessful) {
                            if (response.body()?.meta_data?.success == true && response.body()?.meta_data?.status_code == 201) {
                                toast("Request Sent")
                               brandList.get(pos).has_requested=true
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

                            } else {

                                if (response.body()?.meta_data?.message != null) {
                                    toast(response.body()?.meta_data?.message.toString())

                                } else {


                                    // toast( "no Cars found")
                                }
                            }
                        } else {

                            // nodata.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                            response?.errorBody()?.string()
                                ?.let { responseBody ->
                                    println("Response Body: $responseBody")

                                    try {
                                        // Parse the JSON response to get the error message
                                        val errorJson =
                                            JSONObject(
                                                responseBody
                                            )
                                        val errorMessage =
                                            errorJson.getJSONObject(
                                                "meta_data"
                                            )
                                                .getString("message")
                                        toast(errorMessage)
                                    } catch (e: JSONException) {
                                        e.printStackTrace()
                                        toast("Error parsing server response")
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                    }

                    override fun onFailure(
                        call: Call<ChangeAccountRequest>,
                        t: Throwable
                    ) {
                        loadingDialog.stop()
                        toast(t.message.toString())

                    }

                })
        }
    }


}
```

i want to load data more fast and efficiently

Comment: Is your RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView/ScrollView? If yes, remove NestedScrollView/ScrollView

Comment: yes i got the issue it is due to nested scroll view but i cannot remove that becuase recycler view is at the bottom